# Are the problems with using a big Docker container for multiple tasks?

Tags: docker

I'm working on a scientific computing project. For this work, I need many Python modules as well as C++ packages. The C++ packages require specific versions of other software, so setting up the environment should be done carefully, and after the setup the dependencies should not be updated. So, I thought it should be good to make a Docker container and work inside it, in order to make the work reproducible in the future. However, I didn't understand why people in the internet recommend to use different Docker containers for different processes. For me it seems more natural that I setup the environment, which is a pain, and then use it for the entire project. Can you please explain what I have to be worried about in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It's important that you differentiate between a Docker *image* and a Docker *container*.

People recommend using one process per *container* because this results in a more flexible, scalable environment: if you need to scale out your frontend web servers, or upgrade your database, you can do that without bringing down your entire stack. Running a single process per container also allows Docker to manage those processes in a sane fashion, e.g. by restarting things that have unexpectedly failed. If you're running multiple processes in a container, you end up having to hide this information from Docker by running some sort of process manager, which complicates your containers and can make it difficult to orchestrate a complex application.

On the other hand, it's quite common for someone to use a single image as the basis for a variety of containers all running different services. This is particularly true if you're build a project where a single source tree results in several commands; in that case, it makes sense to have bundle that all into a single image, and then choose which command to run when you start the container.

The only time this becomes a problem is when someone decides to do something like bundle, say, MySQL and Apache into a single image: which is a problem because there are already well maintained official images for those projects, and by building your own you've taking on the burden of properly configuring those services and maintaining the images going forward.

To summarize:

- One process/service per container tends to make your life easier
- Bundling things together in a single image can be okay